# Checking if input value matches the array items

Tags: javascript

I have an array of few items, which are possible passwords, and the code works, but only with one of them. How can i make it work with all the items in the array?

i tried writing
  if (input.value == password[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
but it won't work

input1 is the id of the text field,
button is the id of the button,
here's the script:

```
    var password = new Array("pass1", "pass2", "pass3", "pass4", "pass5");
    var input = document.getElementById("input1");
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        for (var x = 0; x <= password.length; x++) {
            if (input.value == password[0]) {
                document.write("welcome");
                break;
            } else
                alert("wrong");
            break;
        }

    })
```

Comment: Maybe, you can use `if (password.includes(input.value))` in replacement of the `loop`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to replace the entire `for loop` using [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), example:

```js
let password = new Array("pass1", "pass2", "pass3", "pass4", "pass5");
let button = document.getElementById("button");
let input = document.getElementById("input1");

button.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    if (password.includes(input.value))
        alert("welcome");
    else
        alert("wrong");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1">
<button type="button" id="button">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check against an element of the array and return if the value is found, after a welcome.

Put the wrong alert to the end after the loop, because you would get more alerts for every password who does not match.

```
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    for (var x = 0; x <= password.length; x++) {
        if (input.value == password[x]) {
            alert("welcome"); // or take document.getElementById('someid').innerHTML = 'welcome!'
            return;
        }
    }
    alert("wrong");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop to check that. Try `indexOf` to find if value exisits :

```
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (passwords.indexOf(input.value) !== -1) {
    alert("welcome");
  } else {
    alert("wrong");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `if (input.value == password[0])` by `if (input.value == password[x])`in order to check the iterated password.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var passwords = ["pass1", "pass2", "pass3", "pass4", "pass5"];
var input = document.getElementById("input1");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (passwords.some(password => password === input.value)) {
    document.write("welcome");
  } else {
    alert("wrong");
  }
});
```